# android: button not centered when turned from portrait to landscape mode

Tags: android

I have an ImageButton in relative layout with following setup:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#000032">
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="button"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/buttonImage" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It's in both layout and layout-land file.

The button is centered in landscape mode correctly when app started as landscape mode, kept centered when turn the device to portrait mode.

The button is centered in portrait mode correctly when app started as portrait mode, but not centered anymore when turn the device to landscape mode. Not sure why?

Comment: Post your full XML for both layout and layout-land

Comment: @EricBachhuber They're the same as shown above.

Comment: As an aside, android:orientation is a no-op for RelativeLayout.  Also, you might try replacing the two lines (android:layoutCenterHorizontal="true" and android:layoutCenterVertical="true") with this line: android:layout_centerInParent="true"

Comment: @MichaelKrause tried it, doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

in activity used in your `androidmanifest.xml` file
It should work
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Comment: I have this already: android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|fontScale"

Comment: if you use API level 13 or higher  then you should also declare the "screenSize" configuration

Comment: i have try on my phone and work's. Check if something disturbs this

Comment: I think I missed android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" in the normal layout file... it's working now